# Android studio design preview differs from runtime layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I layed out an xml file like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
                android:id="@+id/price_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="50 234 qwerty."/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/discount_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="qwerty 12 3456."/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But the results that appear when app is running differ from the preview window. Particularly the bottom text seems to be cut off. I have the same theme setup in both the app and preview window, I use the same device. Text size on the device is normal. Still it differs - why?

[image: App is running]
[image: Design preview]

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="50 234 qwerty."
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/discount_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="qwerty 12 3456."
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It's not about proper layout, but about the difference.

Answer (score 0):

In android studio, api of preview is 19, then in your emulator api is 18. it seem that dimen of `@android:style/TextAppearance.Large` and `small` was diferent.

Let try with same api in preview and excute code.

Comment: Doesn't change anything except actionbar header text